# Do I need to repair these holes and how to do it if so?

Tags: windows, window-frame

An AC bracket was recently removed from my metal window sill. There are three hole left behind, and I am concerned I may need to do something with them. I put some plastic tape over them (took it off for picture, then reapplied), but I am not sure that is good. On the other hand since it was left like this, it might not be a problem and I don't need to worry. Please let me know if I need to be concerned, and if so, what to do.

The holes
[image]

Comment: I would fill them with some caulking to seal the holes.  The type of caulking will depend if you want to paint over or not.  Silicon will seal but not paintable.

Comment: We have no context from this picture, how big are the holes?  Is this inside or outside? What kind of material are the holes in (metal, stone, wood, etc)? Remove the tape and take a new pic so we can get a better look at the holes. Will you be putting the AC unit (and bracket) back? If so, this needs to be a temporary fix, otherwise you'll want something more permanent. Please [edit] additional info into your questions.

Comment: They are on the outside sill (between the window and the insect net). An AC will be going in there at some point, but not the same AC. Posted new image from a wider angle and without tape.

Comment: The simplest fix might be to just put the screws back in, without the bracket... Personally I would prefer to have them plugged with something and wouldn't worry too much about what.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is in the metal frame of the storm window...

Considering the gap visible here:
[image: Close up snip of the OPs picture highlighting a gap between the storm window frame and the screen pane]

I wouldn't be any more or less concerned about air, water or bugs getting in through the three holes visible below it.

You haven't lost any notable structural integrity of the storm window frame by the presence of these three holes.

*If* wind were to get through these three holes, it wouldn't be more than is getting through the screen above it.

It appears that the edges of the holes *might* have some rough spots that could be smoothed with a file or emery cloth, but if there isn't anything sticking out to snag a finger/cloth/whatever, then it's just an appearance in the picture and this is nothing to worry about.

All in all, there is *NOTHING* to worry about because of these 3 holes beyond cosmetics. Cover it with Scotch tape, caulk, whatever if it makes you feel better. Completely ignore it otherwise.

Comment: The gap you highlighted looks to me like light coming through below the frame of the screen where it sits in the window frame. Water coming through there is likely, but it is also likely that it will come through the screen itself. The holes provide (new) drainage _out_ of the channel in the window frame. A properly flashed installation should still shed the water to the outside, but I wouldn't count on it. Whoever drilled the holes may have pierced the flashing as well. Most of the designs I've seen like this have small channels cut in the bottom of the outer two channel walls for drainage.

Comment: I'd agree, @HABO. i.e. these holes are nothing more or less to worry about than the screen or the gap between the frame and the "screen frame bracket" (or whatever that part's called). In theory, the storm window will be installed without any sort of caulk or anything else along the bottom edge so any water that comes in through the screen will drain out at the bottom instead of sitting and puddling.

Comment: Yeah the screen dosen't do the best job of sealing to the lower frame, but it should be enough to stop most bugs.